# What are the advantages/disadvantages to a declarative template? ViewModel approach?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, mvw

When talking about a declarative syntax in angularjs we usually always bring up directives, and how we can pass `$scope` properties down into these directives for processing, DOM manipulation, data gathering and maybe a various combination of those.

Currently, however I'm struggling to convince my team (let alone myself) that a declarative template is the right approach. That doesn't necessarily mean using directives, but how to use the directives.

The following controller/template pair shows an example where I display an element based on the "model"/$scope's properties.

```
function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.hasJQuery = true;

    $scope.hasProblems = true;

    $scope.hasLodash = false;

    $scope.hasStuff = true;
}

<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <span ng-if="hasJquery && hasProblems && hasLodash && hasStuff">TL;DR?</span>
<div>
```

But the other approach may look like this

```
function MainController2($scope) {
    // Get/Retrieve $scope stuff...

    // Setup "ViewModel" Data
    $scope.hasJQueryAndProblemsAndLodashAndStuff = $scope.hasJQuery && $scope.hasProblems && $scope.hasLodash && $scope.hasStuff;

    $scope.hasJQueryAndLodash = $scope.hasJQuery && $scope.hasLodash;
}

<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <span ng-if="hasJQueryAndProblemsAndLodashAndStuff">...</span>
    <span ng-class="hasJqueryAndLodash ? 'blue' : ''"></span>
</div>
```

The name is an exaggerated version of what could possibly be such as `isReady` or `hasAll` but the point was to show that sometimes the html would require multiple `ng-class` attributes where various logic would rely on `$scope` properties.

I mostly see the first example being what people usually go with - except in cases where the logic gets really complex. Plus I also know that angularjs is a MVW but that really doesn't help me out.

Should I only add "ViewModel" (presentation logic) to `$scope` in the controller sometimes? All the time? Never? And what the advantages/disadvantages of putting presentation logic into the controller/template?

Comment: I'd go for the second, with one change - the name of the checker should be either quite generic (i.e., `isReady()`) or very specific about the condition required, BUT without any details that might change in the future. Still, this question is mostly about opinions. This site isn't.

Comment: @raina77ow Preferring one over another is an opinion, but the reasons that helped you make that decision are what I'm looking for.

Comment: I would put a little logic / angular expressions in the templates as possible as it is harder to test

Comment: @JonSamwell How would it be harder to test? If I setup my `$scope` with mock data the only thing I'd have to test is if the element shows up and I don't even think I should do that since it's an angular directive... Just kindof confused why someone would opt to clutter their `$scope` more with "presentation logic" - Adding more to this question later